# Docker varnish start with command but not with docker-compose

Tags: docker, varnish, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and try to convert my actual web stack in it.
Currently I use this configuration:
varnish -> nginx -> php-fpm -> mysql

I have already convert php-fpm and nginx and now tries varnish.

When I run my image with a command, all is fine but when I put it in docker-compose my container restart indefinitely.

Command:

```
name="varnish"

cd $installDirectory/$name

docker build -t $name .
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a | grep $name | cut -d' ' -f1)

docker run -d -P --name $name \
        -p 80:80 \
        --link nginx:nginx \
        -v /home/webstack/varnish/:/etc/varnish/ \
        -t $name
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
php-fpm:
  restart: always
  build: ./php-fpm
  volumes:
    - "/home/webstack/www/:/var/www/"

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - "/home/webstack/nginx/:/etc/nginx/"
    - "/home/webstack/log/:/var/log/nginx/"
    - "/home/webstack/www/:/var/www/"
  links:
    - "php-fpm:php-fpm"

varnish:
  restart: always
  build: ./varnish
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - "/home/webstack/varnish/:/etc/varnish/"
  links:
    - "nginx:nginx"
```

I have no result with `docker logs webstack_varnish_1` and `docker ps -a` result show:

```
688c5aace1b3        webstack_varnish    "/bin/bash"              16 seconds ago      Restarting (0) 5 seconds ago   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

Here you can see my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:jessie

# Update apt sources
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https
RUN sh -c "curl https://repo.varnish-cache.org/GPG-key.txt | apt-key add -"
RUN echo "deb https://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian/ jessie varnish-4.1" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnish-cache.list

# Update the package repository
RUN apt-get -qq update

# Install varnish
RUN apt-get install -y varnish

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
```

What I am doing wrong please?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the solution here :
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2563

I have to add `tty: true` to my varnish config.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Your varnish Dockerfile seems to be missing `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` directives that would actually launch Varnish.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late. I have already try that solution but I've got the same problem. My question is why with it's work with the command line (no reboot) and not with my docker-compose script ? Thank you.